# what is the difference between session state and query string from user experience point of view?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, user-experience

if I had to send specific value between two web-forms in the same application 
and this value is very small so I have two choices either using query string or session state.

I know the technical differences but 
I am wondering what is the difference between session state and query string from user experience point of view ?

what is/are thing/s that user can do when using "session state" or "query string"  ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, after searching it seems that "session state" has two user experience  problems :

- the back button (DATA WILL BE LOST IF PRESSED )
- multiple taps open (ALL TAPS WILL UPDATE AND MODIFY ON THE SAME SESSION STATE )

WHILE in query string those two problems don't exist.

Comment: 1) Data will not be lost if you return through the page tree it will still be accessible from some session variable. All tabs will update the same session variable yes, that's why session variables are useful...

2) Data will not persist in the same state from page a if you want from a->b-(back)>a (if you revert down the hierarchy) you will lose whatever updated information you were processing on the child page to return to the parent. This answer makes literally 0 sense.

Answer (score 1):

> It depend upon the situation if u need the values on the next page and
>   don't want to use them on any other page then only you use the Query
>   String which is very light weight and if you need that information on
>   some other pages then you store value into the session because this
>   value will be available to you through out the website.

if it's only Between 2 WebForm then you should use `Query String`

**Query String:**

1.Request.QueryString is the query string, meaning the values passed in after the url.

2.
his is good as it only resides as part of the request and not in RAM (or other session state mechanism) but also makes the potentially sensitive data clear to users.  While your application should check authorization whenever data is displayed it does still make the number obvious.  You can encrypt the value which helps.  In general I use this method a lot.

**Session:**

1.Session is something stored in memory (usually) on the server that you can only get access to in C# or server side code.

2. This is OK if it the value is to be used frequently on multiple pages but then tends to load down the server RAM (or other session state holder) in high usage systems.  In general this is not a preferred method for passing a value to just the next page.

Comment: @user5340365 thank you but this not the answer am searching about , i know the technical difference between them  , i am asking about the user experience difference

Comment: what you you mean by `user experience`, will you please explain??@CuzetJess

Comment: " User Experience (UX) involves a person's behaviors, attitudes, and emotions about using a particular product, system or service. "

Comment: i think,max things are listed in my answer.

Comment: I've answered the question and updated the question too.

Answer (score 0):

if we are using view state than View state hold the value per page and if we refresh the page view state will be clear.

But the other hand if we are using session than session hold the value for all pages where we want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Request.QueryString() is used to pass information from one page to another page,which is totally visible to end user in Address url.

Session is something stored in memory (usually) on the server that you can only get access to in C# or server side code.